# A compile error on a download Windows Phone 7 project

Tags: windows-phone-7

I downloaded an windows phone 7 free source code package and start to compile it with my wp7 SDK, but an error happen as below:

**Error 1   The type 'SampleData:SampleDataSource' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built. C:\Users\cofu\Desktop\FlickGestureTest\PanoramaSample\App.xaml  22  7   PanoramaApplication**

I found it is caused by this line in "app.xaml":

```
<SampleData:SampleDataSource x:Key="SampleDataSource" d:IsDataSource="True"/>
```

Then I found the **SampleData** is a folder in my project tree:

ProjectName

---Properties

---Reference

---SampleData

---SampleDataSource(include 2 files as SampleDataSource.xaml and SampleDataSource.xsd)

---App.xaml

---MainPage.xaml

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

Well for starters, you may be missing a using statement....are you?

That's what that error sounds like.

Comment: If this Helped please Vote up!